# 値がゼロのbyte型をstring()して表示するとプログラムが終了？する

Tags: go, vim

以下のコードのように、値がゼロのbyte型の変数をstring()で文字列に変換した値を標準出力に出力しようとすると、キャプチャ画像のようにその時点で停止しました。
また、その状態でEnterキーを押下すると、"End"の文字が表示されることなくプログラムは終了してしまいました。

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    var b byte

    fmt.Println("byte:", b)
    fmt.Println("string:", string(b))

    fmt.Println("End")
}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

なにが起きているのでしょうか？

環境:
Windows7
go version go1.10.3 windows/386
ターミナル：GVIM 8.0.1241（の`:terminal`）

Comment: go 1.10.1 linux/amd64, linux/i386 の場合、この現象は発生しません。端末(terminal)に関係しているのかもしれませんが、プログラムを実行しているのは cmd.exe でしょうか？

Comment: @metropolis まさにおっしゃる通り端末の問題のようでした…。WindowsのGVimの`:terminal`でのみ発生していて、あらためてcmd.exeで試すと発生しませんでした。お手数おかけしました。

Comment: Vim のバグの可能性があります。issue 登録しました。 https://github.com/vim-jp/issues/issues/1181

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己回答です。（metropolisさんのコメントから）

Windows版Vimの`:terminal`固有の問題のようです。
cmd.exeでは再現しません。

mattnさんが [issue](https://github.com/vim-jp/issues/issues/1181) あげてくださいました。